# Java-Accessing value of parent class from child class

Tags: java

Hey I am trying to figure a confusion with accessing a variable's value from parent class in child class.

**Scenario #1**

Below is the code for the class `DrawingPanel()`:

```
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
    private ArrayList<Balloon> balloons;
    private Balloon activeBalloon;
    private boolean picked;
    private int offsetX, offsetY;
    private double offsetR;
    int rotate;

    // Constructor:
    public DrawingPanel()
    {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        addMouseListener(this);
        balloons = new ArrayList<Balloon>();
        activeBalloon = null;
        picked = false;
        rotate = 0;
    }

    // Called from controlPanel when the "Add balloon" button is clicked.
    // Places a new balloon with a random radius and the current color
    // at the center of the drawing panel.
    public void addBalloon(int shape)
    {
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();
        int radius = 10 + (int) (Math.random() * w / 2);
        switch (shape)
        {
        case 1:
            activeBalloon = new SquareBalloon(w / 2, h / 2, radius);
            break;
        default:
            activeBalloon = new SquareBalloon(w / 2, h / 2, radius);
            break;
        }
        balloons.add(activeBalloon);
        repaint();
    }

    // Repaints this panel. If activeBalloon is set, paints it on top.
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Balloon b : balloons)
        {
            if (!picked || b != activeBalloon)
            {
                b.draw(g, true);
            }

        }
        if (picked && activeBalloon != null)
            activeBalloon.draw(g, false);
    }

    // Called when the mouse is clicked on the drawing panel.
    // If inside a balloon, makes it "active", remembers the offsets
    // of the click from the center.
    // If on the border of a balloon, makes it "active", remembers the
    // distance of the click from the center.
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        // Value for parameter rotate is set here on mouse click
        rotate = 2;
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        picked = false;
        for (int k = balloons.size() - 1; k >= 0 && !picked; k--)
        {
            Balloon b = balloons.get(k);
            if (b.isInside(x, y))
            {
                picked = true;
                offsetX = x - b.getX();
                offsetY = y - b.getY();
                activeBalloon = b;

            } else if (b.isOnBorder(x, y))
            {
                picked = true;
                offsetR = b.distance(x, y) - b.getRadius();
                activeBalloon = b;
            }
        }
        if (picked)
            repaint();
    }

    // "Drops" the picked balloon, if any.
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    // Not used:
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }
}
```

Below is the `SquareBalloon()` class which inherits the parent class `Balloon`. The `Balloon` class inherits the `DrawingPanel()` class.

```
public class SquareBalloon extends Balloon implements MouseListener
{
    public SquareBalloon()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a balloon with a given center, radius and color
     * 
     * @param x
     *            x-coordinate of the center
     * @param y
     *            y-coordinate of the center
     * @param r
     *            radius of the balloon
     */
    public SquareBalloon(int x, int y, int r)
    {
        super(x, y, r);
    }

    /**
     * Draws a solid circle if makeItFilled is true and outline only if
     * makeItFilled is false
     * 
     * @param g
     *            graphics context
     * @param makeItFilled
     *            draws a solid circle if true
     */
    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g, boolean makeItFilled)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.setColor(color);
        System.out.println("This is the value of rotate" + rotate + "from the draw() method of SquareBalloon() class.");
        if (makeItFilled)
        {
            Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(xCenter - radius, yCenter - radius, radius, radius);
            if (rotate == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("This is the value of rotate" + rotate
                        + "from the makedItFilled if statement in draw() method of SquareBalloon() class.");
                g2d.rotate(45 * (Math.PI / 180));
            }
            g2d.fill(rect2);

        } else
        {
            Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(xCenter - radius, yCenter - radius, radius, radius);
            if (rotate == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("This is the value of rotate" + rotate
                        + "from the other if statement in draw() method of SquareBalloon() class.");
                g2d.rotate(45 * (Math.PI / 180));
            }
            g2d.draw(rect2);

        }
    }

}
```

**Scenario #2**

Below is the code for the class `DrawingPanel()`:

```
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
    private ArrayList<Balloon> balloons;
    private Balloon activeBalloon;
    private boolean picked;
    private int offsetX, offsetY;
    private double offsetR;
    int rotate;

    // Constructor:
    public DrawingPanel()
    {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        addMouseListener(this);
        balloons = new ArrayList<Balloon>();
        activeBalloon = null;
        picked = false;
        rotate = 0;
    }

    // Called from controlPanel when the "Add balloon" button is clicked.
    // Places a new balloon with a random radius and the current color
    // at the center of the drawing panel.
    public void addBalloon(int shape)
    {
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();
        int radius = 10 + (int) (Math.random() * w / 2);
        switch (shape)
        {
        case 1:
            activeBalloon = new SquareBalloon(w / 2, h / 2, radius);
            break;
        default:
            activeBalloon = new SquareBalloon(w / 2, h / 2, radius);
            break;
        }
        balloons.add(activeBalloon);
        repaint();
    }

    // Repaints this panel. If activeBalloon is set, paints it on top.
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        // to restore original angle of balloon objects
        if (rotate > 2)
            rotate = 0;
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Balloon b : balloons)
        {
            if (!picked || b != activeBalloon)
            {
                b.draw(g, true, rotate);
            }

        }
        if (picked && activeBalloon != null)
            activeBalloon.draw(g, false, rotate);
    }

    // Called when the mouse is clicked on the drawing panel.
    // If inside a balloon, makes it "active", remembers the offsets
    // of the click from the center.
    // If on the border of a balloon, makes it "active", remembers the
    // distance of the click from the center.
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        // Value for parameter rotate is set here on mouse click
        rotate++;
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        picked = false;
        for (int k = balloons.size() - 1; k >= 0 && !picked; k--)
        {
            Balloon b = balloons.get(k);
            if (b.isInside(x, y))
            {
                picked = true;
                offsetX = x - b.getX();
                offsetY = y - b.getY();
                activeBalloon = b;

            } else if (b.isOnBorder(x, y))
            {
                picked = true;
                offsetR = b.distance(x, y) - b.getRadius();
                activeBalloon = b;
            }
        }
        if (picked)
            repaint();
    }

    // "Drops" the picked balloon, if any.
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    // Not used:
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }
}
```

Below is the `SquareBalloon()` class which inherits the parent class `Balloon`. The `Balloon` class inherits the `DrawingPanel()` class.

```
public class SquareBalloon extends Balloon implements MouseListener
{
    public SquareBalloon()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a balloon with a given center, radius and color
     * 
     * @param x
     *            x-coordinate of the center
     * @param y
     *            y-coordinate of the center
     * @param r
     *            radius of the balloon
     */
    public SquareBalloon(int x, int y, int r)
    {
        super(x, y, r);
    }

    /**
     * Draws a solid circle if makeItFilled is true and outline only if
     * makeItFilled is false
     * 
     * @param g
     *            graphics context
     * @param makeItFilled
     *            draws a solid circle if true
     * @param rotate
     *            receives rotate variable value set in mousePressed() method of
     *            DrawingPanel() class
     */
    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g, boolean makeItFilled, int rotate)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.setColor(color);
        System.out.println("This is the value of rotate" + rotate + "from the draw() method of SquareBalloon() class.");
        if (makeItFilled)
        {
            Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(xCenter - radius, yCenter - radius, radius, radius);
            if (rotate == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("This is the value of rotate" + rotate
                        + "from the makedItFilled if statement in draw() method of SquareBalloon() class.");
                g2d.rotate(45 * (Math.PI / 180));
            }
            g2d.fill(rect2);

        } else
        {
            Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(xCenter - radius, yCenter - radius, radius, radius);
            if (rotate == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("This is the value of rotate" + rotate
                        + "from the other if statement in draw() method of SquareBalloon() class.");
                g2d.rotate(45 * (Math.PI / 180));
            }
            g2d.draw(rect2);

        }
    }

}
```

Can someone please explain why in **Scenario #1**, the change in value of variable int rotate after the `mousePressed` method initiates is not being passed to the subclasses of `Balloon` class so that the if statements with condition  `rotate == 2`  in the `draw` method of class `SquareBalloon` executes? Because in **Scenario #2** it does work.

Thank you!

Comment: Code by SO rules should be Minimal ... I see 'rotate' local variable, has nothing to instance fields (so parent instance too). I"m not sue I understand You because of big size

Comment: @JacekCz I am not able to understand your explanation.